# Unable to debug Native app on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, native, lldb

I got this error when I try to debug a simple **native** android app with android studio:

```
Failed to attach native debugger: unable to attach
```

I tied several ideas to solve it. But they didn't work for me.

more information:

- Ubuntu 16.04 (x64)
- java version "1.8.0_91"
- Android Studio v2.1.1
- gradle-experimental:0.7.0
- lldb 2.1

Do you have any idea?

---

**UPDATE**

After installing AVD (Android Virtual Device) on my pc (Ubuntu). Now I am able to debug both java and C++ codes. I think something wrong in my phone or lldb can not run in my phone (?). Do you have any Idea what does cause it?

My phone is HTC.

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging? Emulator or physical device?

Comment: i did it. in my phone I enable developer mode. I can debug java code. but not native.

Comment: OK, I thought you meant Java code by "native", not NDK code

Comment: i followed this tutorial step by step: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html#0

Comment: I have same problem. it's work on Virtual Device too.

Comment: I have same problem with Pax A920 (android edc), The Pax A920 is reject the c/c++ debugger but allow java debugger. Any body can help me how to enable c/c++ debugger in android device?

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle-experimental setup should follow guidelines set forth by google.  You can see their ndk samples of such here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

Essentially, your **android.ndk** block in build.gradle should resemble this:

`android.ndk {
        moduleName = "MostafaModule"
        cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11', '-fexceptions', '-Wall', '-Wno-literal-suffix'])
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni/mostafanativelib")}".toString())
        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
        stl = "gnustl_shared"
}`